# how to handle non contiguous elements in xslt 2.0

Tags: xslt-2.0

I am new to xslt. Please help me how to fix the below mentioned scenario.

**This is the input:**

```
 <parent>
       <c1>some text</c1>
       <c2>some text</c2>
       <c2>some text</c2>
       <c2>some text</c2>
       <c3>some text</c3>
       <c2>some text</c2>
       <c2>some text</c2>
       <c2>some text</c2>
       <c3>some text</c3>
       <c2>some text</c2>
        <c2>some text</c2> </parent>
```

I want my output like below: (all the c2,till it encounter c3, should be nested into a single c2). The problem is, c3 is not an fixed element. It can be any element other than c2.

```
<parent> 
    <c1>some text</c1> 
    <c2>some text
        some text
        some text</c2>
    <c3>some text</c3>
    <c2>some text
        some text
        some text</c2>
    <c3>some text</c3>
    <c2>some text
        some text</c2>
</parent>
```

Comment: See the `group-adjacent` example in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping-examples, should be easy with `group-adjacent="boolean(self::c2)"`. If you are stuck, post your effort.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:template match="parent">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="name() = 'c2'">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```